# Get dropdown status for a ToolStripDropDown object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Despite looking several times I can't find anything in the documentation that returns a simple status of whether or not a dropdown is open or not.  I'd like to create a click event for toolstrip submenus that will open or close the items dropdown depending on its status.

I'm likely overlooking it because it seems like such a basic method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the [ToolStripDropDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object returned from the ToolStripDropDownItem.DropDown property you should be able to get what you need from the [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property... if that doesn't work then you could check the [Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.region%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value to test if its currently on screen.

Comment: Visible was it.  Thanks.