# Need to check dropdown opened state in toolstripmenu item from menustrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to check if dropdown is opened or not in toolstripmenuitem. Iam used this below code.

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem Tm_items in menustrp.Items){                  
       if (Tm_items.DropDown.Visible == true){    

       }
}
```

here iam using **visible**  to check, But that doesnt work for my condition.It shows only if it is visible. I need to check once the dropdown is opened.

I want to check something like this ..

```
 if(Tm_items.DropDown.opened == true)
{
   here i want to do something.

}
```

Please help me out.  iam trying this for past 2 days. It will be more helpfull for me if there is a solution.

Thanks,
sridhar

Comment: Can you post a screen of that Control with the DropDown? Since there are only `ComboBox`, `SplitButton` and `DropDownButton` providing a DropDown in Toolstrip. Or do you mean the `OverflowButton`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849549/get-dropdown-status-for-a-toolstripdropdown-object

Comment: Iam using Menustrip. So getting all the items by toolstrip. I have already tried **visible** property. But i want to check, if dropdown is opened immediately, not when it is visible .

Comment: Any solutiions will be much helpfull @lokusking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as answer since it contains code

In your Form's constructor you could do something like this:

```
public Form1() {

      InitializeComponent();

      foreach (ToolStripMenuItem Tm_items in menustrp.Items) {
        Tm_items.DropDownOpened += (sender, args) => {
          MessageBox.Show("Open"); // Perform logic here
        };

      }
}
```

Subscribe to the according Event which tells you, if the Dropdown was opened.

You might also subscribe to the `DropDownClosed`-event if you want to take care if it was closed again

**Note**

This only handles the First-Level-Items of your Menu!

Comment: Thank you very much !! It worked . You are great :) @lokusking